# Spark Java - How do I iterate rows in dataframe Dataset<Row>, and add values of one column to an Arraylist

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a `Dataset<Row>` containing `3 columns`  in `Java`. I want to iterate on its rows, then add the values of this column to an `ArrayList`. Could anyone help me?

Please take on consideration that I work in `Java`.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `arrayList.addAll(dataset.collect());`?

Comment: I will try it @ErnestKiwele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Ernest Kiwele.

it worked in this way :

```
List<Row> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
arrayList=dataset.collectAsList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dataset.forEach( row -> syso(row));

Comment: what is `syso`?

Comment: System.out.println